# Not an ARRAY reference when trying to trying to update old Perl code. Hash to Array issue?

Tags: arrays, perl, parsing, hashtable

I am trying to update an outdated perl plugin to Google's new API (They changed their search call). I'm new to Perl so I'm not sure how to correctly update the code. I'm pretty sure I'm trying to read a hash when it's supposed to be an array?

Data Structure Dumped:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'station_hits' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1726698624)}, 'Inline::Python::Object' ),
          'album_hits' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1726698288)}, 'Inline::Python::Object' ),
          'artist_hits' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1726698336)}, 'Inline::Python::Object' ),
          'situation_hits' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1726698384)}, 'Inline::Python::Object' ),
          'song_hits' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1726698432)}, 'Inline::Python::Object' ),
          'playlist_hits' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1726698480)}, 'Inline::Python::Object' ),
          'video_hits' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1726698528)}, 'Inline::Python::Object' )
        };
```

Code Block:

```
# Search All Access
sub search {
        my $query = shift;

        return unless $prefs->get('all_access_enabled');

        my $uri = 'googlemusic:search:' . $query;

        if (my $result = $cache->get($uri)) {
                return $result;
        }

        my $googleResult;
        my $result = {
                tracks => [],
                albums => [],
                artists => [],
        };

        eval {
                $googleResult = $googleapi->search($query, $prefs->get('max_search_items'));
        };

        if ($@) {
                $log->error("Not able to search All Access for \"$query\": $@");
                return;
        }
        #My Attempt
        for my $hit (%@{$googleResult->{song_hits}}) {
                push @{$result->{tracks}}, to_slim_track($hit->{track});
        }
        #How it was originally
        for my $hit (@{$googleResult->{album_hits}}) {
                push @{$result->{albums}}, album_to_slim_album($hit->{album});
        }
```

I'm getting this error after making only a name change:

Not an ARRAY reference at [LINE#]

Changed **search_all_access** to **search**

Line in question:

```
for my $hit (@{$googleResult->{song_hits}}) {
```

I tried researching and **added a % in front**, but now I am getting an error on the following line.

'newlist' object has no attribute 'track' at [LINE#+1]

```
 push @{$result->{tracks}}, to_slim_track($hit->{track});
```

EDIT: 
After making the changes after explaining well how referencing a hash is supposed to work, I get this:

```
 [16-05-23 10:22:36.7283] Slim::Networking::IO::Select::__ANON__ (131) Error: Select task failed calling Slim::Web::HTTP::processHTTP: Can't locate object method "FIRSTKEY" via package "Inline::Python::Object::Data" at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.20/Data/Dumper.pm line 224.
; fh=Slim::Web::HTTP::ClientConn=GLOB(0x1007a188)
```

I'm not sure if there was an existing error in their code or that Google is returning the API data in a different structure after this latest error.

Comment: I am a little uncertain as to what you are trying to change/update? The `%\@{...}` is not valid syntax -- you can either dereference an array, `@{$arrayref}`, or a hash, `%{$hashref}`.  What is the "dump" you are showing?  What is shown is: (1) a hashref, so you'd retrieve values by `$href->{key}`, (2) the values are formally objects, since `bless` returns an object.  Can you clarify this a bit?

Comment: google changed their search function on their api to one universal search call instead of a separate subscription and regular user function. It was supposed to only be a naming change, so unsure if there was already a bug in this existing Perl code or they return their data differently

Comment: Ah, yes they'll do that.  So the old code is broken now -- the code under `# How it was originally` (for `album_hits`) isn't working? If it cannot find a method , (when you changed it to hash)  that may be due to python's `object`, which may build on top of Python's builtins (as I understand) and may not be well understood (bound) by `Inline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These objects seem to be abstracted away. You can read the [Inline::Python](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Inline-Python/Python.pod) documentation, but there's nothing about it. In the [code for the Inline::Python::Object](https://metacpan.org/source/NINE/Inline-Python-0.49/Python.pm#L311) however, there is a hint.

Two lines down, there is this (omission mine).

> ```
> use overload '%{}' => \&__data__, # [...]
> ```

If it has [an overload](http://perldoc.perl.org/overload.html) for when it's used with a hash dereference we can be pretty sure it will return a hash ref in that case.

Now all we need to do is fix your syntax error that you introduced. You did `%@{}`, which is not valid syntax. Instead of the array deref `@{}`, you need `%{}`.

```
for my $hit (%{ $googleResult->{song_hits} }) {
        push @{$result->{tracks}}, to_slim_track($hit->{track});
}
```

But because hashes in Perl are essentially lists, you will now iterate over both the keys and the values. That's hardly ever a good idea. Instead, you should [iterate over the `keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html), and then work with that. Or more likely, there is only one key in each of them that you are interested in. If there is an API description, I suggest you check it. It might be helpful here.

If not, `Dumper` it like this.

```
print Dumper \%{ $googleResult->{song_hits} };
```

That dereferences it first, making sure that overload is called. Because Data::Dumper doesn't understand lists as data structures, you are passing it a reference to the returned hash, so you get `$VAR1={}` instead of `$VAR1='foo'; $VAR2='bar'` and so on.

Comment: Does this mean that `overload` will force it to a hashref?  I thought that "_How it was ..._" is (presumably) correct, so `@{$googleResult->{album_hits}}` indicates that data is in arrayref.

Comment: thanks simbaque, I think I accidentally tried this earlier after all! I remember this error, so I thought I did it incorrect. You explained it perfectly.  I get now [16-05-23 10:22:36.7283] Slim::Networking::IO::Select::__ANON__ (131) Error: Select task failed calling Slim::Web::HTTP::processHTTP: Can't locate object method "FIRSTKEY" via package "Inline::Python::Object::Data" at /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/perl/5.20/Data/Dumper.pm line 224.
; fh=Slim::Web::HTTP::ClientConn=GLOB(0x1007a188). 

Any ideas as to if it means first 'key' in a hash?

Comment: No, it means that method isn't found. The is an autoload there. That's strange.

Comment: Looks like Inline::Python::Object::Data only provides a limited hash interface.  It will let you look up the value for a given key or set it but not find out what the available keys are.

Comment: From what I understand Python's `object` allows one to build on top of builtins, creating trouble for `Inline` to bind things correctly.  Perhaps using Inline's `bind` explicitly may help.

Comment: I think we would need a working example to debug this further. Only reading code and speculating is not going to get us anywhere. @CREW, can you provide a [mcve]? This is the Play Music API, right? I have a subscription myself and can try to debug if you give me something I can run.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Data::Dumper to print out those data structures you will soon see what form they are in.Then you won't have to guess. Also don't mistake the object oriented calling style with hash access. , they are they same because that's how Perl5 objects are made.

```
use data::dumper;
print "variable is :" + Dumper(@variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what is the intended "*update*", what needs to be changed. But here are a few comments.

First: the syntax is invalid -- one cannot have `%@{...}`. You can *dereference* a reference to either a hash, `%{$hashref}`, or to an array, `@{$arrayref}` (or to scalar, `$$scalarref`).

---

Your data structure is interesting.  First, it is a hash reference. (Or, rather, an *anonymous hash*.)  You can either dereference it altogether to create a hash, or can pull values for specific keys as

```
my $href = { 'k1' => 'val1', 'k2' => 'val2' };
my $value_of_k1_key = $href->{'k1'};            # will be == val1
```

Next, the 'value' in your code is formally an object. The `bless` function associates a reference to a data structure (usually a hashref) with a class, making it an object of that class (which it returns).

So you really have

```
$href = { 'station_hits' => $object, ... }
```

After you query (any of) the keys, you are getting back that object.

```
$object = $googleResult->{song_hits}
```

According to code shown under "*# How it was originally*" (which I presume works), the object's data structure is a reference to an array, not a hash, since it dereferences an array. That's OK.  The odd part is that it dereferences it directly, seeking its data/attributes. In terminology of some other languages, it is accessing (presumably) private members.  In Perl that is legal and will retrieve a value but it is generally considered as bad as if it were banned.